# Tomcat servlet logging

Tags: apache, tomcat, logging, servlets

I'm new to Servlet containers and have created a web application using Tomcat 6.0.26.  I have 'TODO: log' scattered throughout my code.  I see there exists:

myServlet.getServletContext().log()

which appears to write to a file prefixed with 'localhost' in the Tomcat '/logs' directory.  I don't need any advanced logging capability, but I'd like a date, time, message and stack trace at minimum.  In addition, I've created some classes used by my various servlets that need logging capabilities as well. Do I need to inject a SevletContext into these classes so they can log?

It appears that log4j from Apache is a popular logging package, but I'm not sure if it worth the trouble of setting it up.

What would be the recommended way of logging for my needs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to all the stuff BalusC has mentioned above, in your java code (servlets/beans/whatever) just import and initialize the Logger

```
package my.app;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("classname");
// use any string you want
```

Then at any logging point you can log at various levels like

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Some log at this point");
        }

...

logger.info("Some info message here");
```

These will appear in the logs depending on whether you set DEBUG or INFO in the log4j.propeties

Take a look at the examples on http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Examplelog4jConfigurationFile.htm and all the Related examples in the same article

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I couldn't seem to find this connecting piece of the puzzle.

As an aside, is there a reason the logging facility built into the JDK isn't used more frequently?

Comment: @Wilson - more on that debate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840/java-logging-vs-log4j and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582428/java-util-logging-logger-and-log4j

Comment: @JoseK - Is there a simple way to log servlet activity into a file without log4j or console ? I have posted a question for this. Please help me at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858552/simple-way-to-log-servlet-in-tomcat

Answer (score 12):

You don't want to tie up all your business and data access code with the `ServletContext` (I of course assume that your business and DB code is not tight coupled inside a servlet class, but just live in their own layer of classes, without any `javax.servlet` references). So I wouldn't recommend to use `ServletContext#log()`. It's also very seldom used in real world.

You're right that log4j is popular, even though it's been succeeded by [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). Setting up log4j doesn't need to be that troublesome. I suggest to start with a properties file which is less hard to understand than a XML file. You can always upgrade to a XML file once you understand what's going on in log4j configuration.

Create a file named `log4j.properties`, put it somewhere in the root of the classpath, e.g. `/WEB-INF/classes` (or if you're using an IDE, the root of the `src` folder, it will eventually land in the right place). You can also keep it outside the webapp and add its path to the server's runtime classpath by specifying its path in `shared.loader` property of `Tomcat/conf/catalina.properties`. Finally fill it as follows:

```
# Set root logger level and appender name.
log4j.rootLogger = TRACE, console

# Specify appenders.
log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

# Configure console appender.
log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %m%n

# Configure file appender.
log4j.appender.file.File = /webapp/logs/web.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %m%n
```

This kickoff example by default logs at a level of `TRACE`. You can change it to `DEBUG` or `INFO` like so:

```
# Set root logger level and appender name.
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, console
```

This example also by default uses the console appender. It will log to the standard output as it is configured by Tomcat which by default lands in the `/logs/localhost.yyyy-MM-dd.log` file.

You can however change it to use the file appender like so:

```
# Set root logger level and appender name.
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, file
```

The `ConversionPattern` settings can be found in detail in the [`PatternLayout` javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

Hope this helps to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The main disconnect I have in understanding how to use Log4j is how to use it from code.  How do I use it in a Servlet, in beans, in POJOs?  Do I need to create a Log4j instance, then find and parse the properties or XML file?

Comment: Just use `Logger#getLogger()` and then `debug()`, `info()`, etc methods. You don't need to find and parse it everytime. If it's in the classpath, log4j will do it itselves. It's indeed a common problem among starters because they don't understand "classpath".

Comment: Echoing what BalusC said, [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) + [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) is the more modern way to do logging. Created by the inventor of log4j, and meant to be the successor of log4j. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19947417/642706) to [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933036/simplest-way-to-log-to-tomcat-catalina-out/19947417#19947417) for more info.

Comment: @BalusC - Is there a simple way to log servlet activity into a file without log4j or console ? I have posted a question for this. Please help me at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858552/simple-way-to-log-servlet-in-tomcat