# What is the simplest quick-and-dirty way to start logging Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

In [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), what is the easiest quick-and-dirty way to do some logging in a fresh project?

The documentation, such as [FAQ/Logging](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging) and [Logging in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html), are overwhelming. I just want to spit out some text to see if my new project is working.

Yes, I know eventually I will need to add [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) and [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) (etc.), but what can I do in the meantime?

I'm using NetBeans 8 Beta. So, it would be convenient to see my logging output from inside NetBeans. But at this point I'd settle for going into the file system to open a text file manually.

Comment: logging where in a file or console? and Logging what, I mean what would be the content of log?

Comment: Why not just `System.out.println` ? It would print it in the `catalina.out` file.

Comment: @sakura Where? Anywhere. What content? Anything, "hello world".

Comment: @ShashankKadne Nope, at least when running NetBeans, System.out does not feed into catalina.out.

Comment: exactly `sysout` is the dirtiest & quickest way..it will print on Netbeans console.. By the way.. your question is very subjective and am afraid if there is any to the point answer.

Comment: @sakura Subjective? How is "logging 'hello world' from a servlet in Tomcat in NetBeans" subjective?

Comment: @BasilBourque : That output you should see in the Tomcat Console in Netbeans.

Comment: By Subjective I meant broad and open for discussion. quickest and dirtiest ways can be different for different developers based on there own reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add my two cents here.

Just to start with logging without any configuration hassle, here is what I usually do.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggingDemo {
    //First, you instantiate a logger object as a member
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( LoggingDemo.class.getName() );

    public Object someMethod( Object someParameter ) {
        // Then, use the logger wherever you want
        logger.info("some message");
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. I edited my answer to make a hybrid of (a) my one-liner, and (b) your call to `.info` rather than `.log`. That shortened the length of my line. Is there any other difference between yours and mine, besides splitting the one-liner to create an instance variable?

Comment: Well, for starters, you don't have to repeat this part `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger( YourClassNameGoeshere.class.getName() )` over and over

Comment: Thanks, got it. Using single-line vs multi-line depends on how quick-and-dirty the situation is. For getting started, or for throwaway projects, my one-liner is preferable. If getting serious enough to hold the logger in an instance variable, my own preference is to jump to using SLF4J and LogBack rather than use Java’s built-in logging feature. My situation today was needing to make a tiny sample Servlet project to investigate and report a possible bug in Tomcat; that being a throw-away project, and needing to share the code with others, meant I needed the simplest possible code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19934124/642706) in another question. I'll provide more detail here.

In one line…  ( replace `YourClassNameGoeshere` & `YourMessageGoesHere` )

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger( YourClassNameGoeshere.class.getName() ).info( "YourMessageGoesHere" );
```

In NetBeans 8 Beta, the log entry appears on screen on the *Output* tab, on the nested tab named for the web server such as *Apache Tomcat 8.0.3 Beta*.

[image]

The entry will look something like this:

> 01-Mar-2014 22:33:33.957 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] BackgroundTaskControl.contextInitialized Basil says 'hello world'.

Comment: Oooo.. so this is your dirtiest and quickest way... Ahhhh!! Nice. :)

Comment: **Cons:** It is long. It is ugly. It uses the logging facility built into Java, which is less than optimal. **Pros:** Simple one-liner. No added libraries. No configuration. Easy to copy-paste-edit. Log entries appear by default in NetBeans on-screen. **Tip:** For real work, one should use [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) and [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/).